# Error when starting squid

Tags: proxy, squid

i am getting this error when i am starting up squid, it is running on a mac mini

```
cache_cf.cc(346) squid.conf:4871 unrecognized: 'https_port'
```

Comment: could you please copy+paste line 4871 of your squid.conf?

Answer (score 0):

I just re-installed squid and the error disappeared.

I was lucky that I had not setup any configurations yet.